# For quasi-simple groups, $G=O^p(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite quasi-simple group and $p$ be a prime number. Show that $G=O^p(G)$.

Here, $O^p(G)= \langle x\in G: p\nmid |x|\rangle$.

**My attempt:** An alternate formulation of $O^p(G)$ is that it is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ such that the factor group is a $p$-group. Due to this if $G=O^p(G)$, then $G/G$ would be a $p$-group which contradicts that $p$ is prime. So, I always thought that $O^p(G)$ is a proper subgroup. How can $G=O^p(G)$ unless $G=1$?

Comment: The trivial group is a $p$-group for all primes $p$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven So, prime-power means that the power can be $0$? I didn't know this, thank you! Could you give  me a hint to get started on this problem?

Comment: This problem is fairly easy, so you should be able to do it by yourself now that your misunderstanding about $p$-groups has been sorted out. In brief, if $G \ne O^p(G)$, then $G/O^p(G)$ is a nontirival $p$-group, which is not perfect, so $G$ is not perfect.

Comment: @DerekHolt Right, I got it. But then the result holds for all perfect groups, correct? We don't need quasi-simplicity!

Comment: Yes, that's right!